# Filter in one line of code and show only certain columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. On the one hand, I would like to filter or select my dataframe and on the other hand, I would like to output only certain columns directly. I can't find anything (maybe I'm missing the terms). Is there an option to filter directly in pandas in only one row and at the same time output only certain columns?

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
     'name': ['Max Power', 'Jessica', 'Xi', 'Jackson', 'Frank', 'Miller'],
     'secondName': ['Full', 'Miller', 'Hu', 'Johnny', 'High', 'Joachim'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)

df_new = df[df['id'] == 1]
display(df_new[['id', 'name']])

# df_new = df[['id', 'name'], df['id'] == 1] # TypeError Name: id, dtype: bool)' is an invalid key

[OUT]

id  name    secondName
0   1   Max Power   Full
1   2   Jessica Miller
2   3   Xi  Hu
3   4   Jackson Johnny
4   5   Frank   High
5   1   Miller  Joachim
id  name
0   1   Max Power
5   1   Miller
```

What I want

```py
df[df['id'] == 1, ['id','name']]
id  name
0   1   Max Power
5   1   Miller
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - first is defined boolean mask and then list of columns names:

```
print(df.loc[df['id'] == 1, ['id','name']])
   id       name
0   1  Max Power
5   1     Miller
```